# How do I parse a CSV file located in a Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, heroku, amazon-s3

Below is the code I'm using to parse the CSV from within the app, but I want to parse a file located in a Amazon S3 bucket. It needs to work when pushed to Heroku as well.

```
namespace :csvimport do
  desc "Import CSV Data to Inventory."
  task :wiwt => :environment do
    require 'csv'

    csv_file_path = Rails.root.join('public', 'wiwt.csv.txt')

    CSV.foreach(csv_file_path) do |row|
      p = Wiwt.create!({
        :user_id => row[0],
        :date_worn => row[1],
        :inventory_id => row[2],
      })
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 15):

There are cases with S3, when permissions on S3 Object disallow public access. In-built Ruby functions do assume a path is publicly accessible and don't account for AWS S3 specificity.

```
s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new
bucket = s3.bucket("bucket_name_here")
str = bucket.object("file_path_here").get.body.string
content = CSV.parse(str, col_sep: "\t", headers: true).map(&:to_h)
```

Per-line explanation using AWS SDK:
Line 1. Initialize
Line 2. Choose a bucket.
Line 3. Choose an object and get it as a String.
Line 4. Effectively CSV.parse('the string'), but I also added a options and map over it just in case it helps you.

Comment: This is a good answer; should be upvoted more.  My only comment is that instead of doing .get.body.string, just do .get.body, which returns StringIO, which CSV.parse can handle.  This will be more performant than converting to string first.

Answer (score 8):

You can do it like this

```
CSV.new(open(path_to_s3)).each do |row|
  ...
end
```

Comment: CSV.load gave me a *NoMethodError: private method 'load' called for CSV:class*, but it lead me to **CSV.new**, which worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
  open(s3_file_path) do |file|
    CSV.foreach(file, {headers: true, header_converters: :symbol}) do |row|
      Model.create(row.to_hash)
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the csv file from S3 like this:

```
require 'csv'
require 'net/http'

CSV.parse(Net::HTTP.get(s3_file_url), headers: true).each do |row|
# code for processing row here
end
```